# jQuery dropdown value change depending on the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" id="defectstatus" name="defectstatus">
   <option selected="selected" value="Pick One">Select Defect Status</option>
   <option value="New">New</option>
   <option value="Needs more info">Needs more info</option>
```

Now I have a variable

```
a=$("#answer").html();
alert(a);
```

For which the value of a is

```
New
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
$("#defectstatus").val(a);
```

Then my dropdown defectstatus will change default selected to New instead of Pick One

Comment: Nevermind. Didn't the see the output value

Comment: Whatever you have seems to work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/czbv0hag/ . Whats the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you trying to select the option with the value is (New) you can use

```
$("#defectstatus > option[value='"+ a +"']").prop('selected' , true);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but still it doesn't work.The dropdown selected doesn't change

Comment: @Chong maybe you need to trim the html() to avoid left and right white spaces .. you can use  a=$.trim($("#answer").html());

Answer (score 0):

You try change `$("#answer").text();` instead of `$("#answer").html();`

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems like it works, but I imagine it's possible that your code is executing before the HTML has loaded, and is therefore not finding `#answer`.

You can wrap your code in `$(function(){/*code*/});` to make sure it executes when the document is ready.

(Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PMOraMzVsMEg2z3FOeP5?p=preview)